# React Native CameraRoll File Upload

Tags: swift, react-native, react-native-ios, react-native-native-module

I am trying to build a custom image gallery that user can select multiple images from it and upload by FormData but on iOS from CameraRoll library it gets ph://SOMETEXT kinda uri which is a "LocalIdentifier" and its described on this issue https://github.com/react-native-community/react-native-cameraroll/issues/195#issuecomment-655549166 and i am trying make a swift bridge to implement that function can return a real uri of the image as he is explaining but when I try

```
let photo = PHAsset.fetchAssets(withLocalIdentifiers: 
['localUriGotFromReactNativeCameraRool'], options: .none).firstObject
```

in my function it always returns empty object without the actual image

this is my full code

```
import Foundation
import Photos
@objc(RNFetchAssets)
class RNFetchAssets: NSObject {


  @objc
  func fetch(
    _ localUri: String,
    resolve: RCTPromiseResolveBlock,
    rejecter reject: RCTPromiseRejectBlock
  ) -> Void {

  let requestOptions = PHImageRequestOptions()
  requestOptions.isSynchronous = false
  let photo = PHAsset.fetchAssets(withLocalIdentifiers: [localUri], options: .none).firstObject
  print(photo ?? "None");
  //resolve(photo)

  }

  private func fetchOptions() -> PHFetchOptions {
  
      let fetchOptions = PHFetchOptions()
  
      fetchOptions.sortDescriptors = [NSSortDescriptor(key: "creationDate", ascending: false)]
      return fetchOptions
     }


  @objc
  static func requiresMainQueueSetup() -> Bool {
   return true
 }

 }
```

Comment: the problem was the "ph://" prefix of the local identifier i removed it and it gets the phasset now but i dont know how to convert it into a filename,type,uri object so javascript can read it